# How to learn to write idiomatic c++ code

Tags: c++, boost, stl, idioms

I recently forced myself to study C++ and I just finished reading the book C++: The Complete Reference, by Herbert Schildt. I liked the book and think I got more or less the big picture. I noticed though that when I try to check with other people the things I code using the material I learned, they are usually considered non-idiomatic and superseded by an STL way to do it that is safer and easier (well, the book doesn't cover STL and Boost libraries).

So I'd like to ask: what are good sources to learn the patterns of a good C++ program? Where can I learn basic patterns from the "C++ way" to do things and not just repeating C patterns in C++?

I'd be particularly interested in sources that included STL and Boost stuff.

Comment: why not the STL and Boost docs?

Comment: Because they suck as a teaching aid and weren’t intended as such.

Comment: For the same reason you can't learn to drive by reading the owner's manual.

Comment: @John Dibling: funny, i did exactly that!

Comment: @Javier: learning *is* teaching oneself. And yes, learning with a manual is certainly possible but it’s far from the best way.

Comment: @Javier:  I'm sure you're a great driver, too. ;)

Comment: Well, this is what I'm reading right now! :) But not everything is clear from the docs and reference manuals in a first look, and a text in english (or any other human language I can read) really explaining the basics can help a lot.

Comment: Herbert Schildt's C++ books [are **highly not recommended** by the C++ community](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391091/should-i-not-use-a-herb-schildt-book-to-learn-from). You're much better off reading a [C++ book by people who actually know what they're talking about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Oh boy... I wish I could've read this before buying the book. :P Well, I'll try to get other books.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might wnat to check out [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

For your purposes I would especially recommend:

- [C++ Coding Standards](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321113586)
- [Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201924889)
- [Beyond the C++ Standard Library: An Introduction to Boost](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321133544)
- [Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670)
- [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) (Examples in Java, still valid though.)

They are not in particular order, also you might want to read and code something in between them.

(Note: As noted by @John Dibling the Boost book might be a bit out of date, I do not have experience with that one myself)

Comment: overall +1, but I can't recommend the boost book. I found it to be hopelessly out of date, and not applicable to my actual needs.

Comment: The first two. Then he'll need Stroustrup's The C++ Programming Language to use as a reference.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have completed the Herbert Schildt book, you can read the book by the Bjarne Stroustrup ([The C++ Programming Language](http://books.google.com/books?id=Bk4iAQAAIAAJ&q=the+c%2B%2B+programming+language+by+bjarne+stroustrup)) or Bruce Eckel's book ([Thinking in C++ Part 1 & Part 2](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html)). The Eckel's book is freely available on the internet and Part-2 talks about STL.

Comment: +1, Eckel books are really good

Comment: For reading and basic learning, yes, but they are also a bit dated, and mostly non ideomatic Modern C++.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to learn how to write C++ idiomatic code is ... to write C++ code and to have your code reviewed by some advanced C++ developer.
You should also read some of the most famous C++ books (Effective C++ by Scott Meyers is a good start, Modern C++ Design is a bad book to learn how to write nice C++ code but is a great book if you want to discover and understand the concept of generic programming).

On top of all that, you should read much doc about STL and boost and learn a lot about iterators. Iterators are the key to use STL (and boost implementation of containers and algorithms) and if you don't know how to use them, you won't write C++ idiomatic code. Ever.

Answer (score 1):

[Accelerated C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020170353X) is an introduction to C++ that uses the STL from the very beginning.  It's not a long book, but it's "dense" and a great choice for someone in your situation IMO.  My experience with C++ was similar to yours when I read it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd (also) recommend:

- [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876), [Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629) by Steve Myers. They are easy to digest, yet very valuable - sometimes even illuminating.
- [Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) (The 1993 edition is available cheaply and not that much different). It's lengthy, but it walks across the entire field from *what it means to be a programmer* to *how a for loop should look*. (It would be better if it was shorter - the way it is it covers so much ground it's hard to place it). I hold it dear because it illustrate two points very well:

  - code is compromise
  - There are know facts, (but we still manage to get by by gut feel)
- [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/) / [C++ FAQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201309831).
- I'd throw in [Facts and Fallacies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321117425) by Robert Glass - it doesn't fit your request very well, but go read it.

---

It's natural that you are unhappy with other people's code. That's typical for programming - heck, even *my own code* of five years ago was written by a total n00b. That might be more articulated for C++, since it caters for different styles, and often puts freedom ("you can") over guildelines ("that's the way").

Still, mulling over existing code - yours or others - and considering how it can be improved. Also, figuring out *why* it is the way it is sometimes helps.

---

(I remember a few TheDailyWTF's where everyone would chime in how stupid and unreasonable this is - yet somewhere, buried among the me too's, was someone with domain experience explaining convincingly under what circumstances this was better than the obvious solution).